# I am trying to call a db2 procedure but I am runtime error com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException

Tags: hibernate, db2

I am calling a db2 procedure but I am getting runtime error `

> "com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException"

`.This runtime error says there is a syntax error but I am not able to figure out what exactly is wrong with my code. Can anybody help me out, please?

```
public String  getReferenceno(String Product_Code) throws SQLException
{

    String reference_no=null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement;
    try {
        System.out.println(Product_Code);

     //callableStatement = connection_new().prepareCall("CALL IPS_DB.GET_SEQUENCE_NUMBER(?,?)");
    callableStatement = connection_new().prepareCall("{Call IPS_DB.GET_SEQUENCE_NUMBER(?,?)}");


    callableStatement.setString(1, Product_Code);

    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);

    callableStatement.execute();

    //reference_no = (String) callableStatement.getString(2);

    connection_new().close();


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
         return "error";
    }


    return reference_no ;
  }
```

Comment: Insufficient information. Edit your question to add jdbc full exception text stacktrace, (showing the driver version of jdbc type and details of the error thrown by the Db2 driver), add the environment details (operating-system for client and server, versions of software etc).

Comment: Do you get the exception on prepare or execute? What happens when you call your procedure by other means, e.g. using the command-line processor?

Comment: I am getting exception at  callableStatement.execute() @mustaccio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be useful to see the definition of the `IPS_DB.GET_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` procedure and the exact SQLCODE returned.

E.g. if I would execute `CALL MYSP(...)` with an incorrect number of (or incompatible) arguments then also `com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException` will be thrown:

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=MULTIPLY_BY_THREE;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=3.72.52
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=MULTIPLY_BY_THREE;PROCEDURE, DRIVER=3.72.52
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b1.a(b1.java:813)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b1.a(b1.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b1.a(b1.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kj.c(kj.java:2790)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kj.d(kj.java:2778)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kj.a(kj.java:2222)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kk.a(kk.java:7643)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.i(ab.java:148)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.e(ab.java:77)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.d(p.java:63)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.m(av.java:185)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kj.ak(kj.java:2217)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kk.bn(kk.java:3602)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kk.a(kk.java:4460)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.b(CallableStatement.java:128)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.a(CallableStatement.java:103)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:93)
```

and from SQLCODE I can learn that a matching routine was not found:

```
db2 ? sqln440

SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "<routine-name>" of type
      "<routine-type>" having compatible arguments was found.
```

which implies that the code itself is OK.

This is a working example of `CallableStatement` execution:

1. SP definition:

```
db2 "create or replace procedure multiply_by_two(in input int, out output int)
    language sql
    set output = input*2"
```

2. Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.ibm.db2.jcc.*;

public class so
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String            url;
        CallableStatement cstmt;
        Connection        c;
        Properties        props = new Properties();

        if (args.length != 5)
        {
          System.out.println("USAGE: java so db_name hostname portnum username password");
          return;
        }

        url = "jdbc:db2://"+args[1]+":"+args[2]+"/" + args[0];

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();

            props.put("user",args[3]);
            props.put("password",args[4]);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);

            cstmt = c.prepareCall("CALL MULTIPLY_BY_TWO(?,?)");
            cstmt.setInt(1,10);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
            cstmt.execute();
            int out = cstmt.getInt(2);
            System.out.println("MULTIPLY_BY_TWO returned: " + out);
            cstmt.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Execution complete.");
    }
}
```

3. Compilation:

```
 ~/sqllib/java/jdk64/bin/javac so.java
```

4. Execution:

```
~/sqllib/java/jdk64/bin/java so sample localhost  60111 db2v111 passw0rd
MULTIPLY_BY_TWO returned: 20
Execution complete.
```